# Does removing the (1) in $\Phi{(1)}$ affect the proof that $ K_0 \leq_m K$ or not?

Tags: logic, computability

The fragment below from Martin Davis' book shows $ K_0 \leq_m K$ and also proves $ K_0 \leq_1 K $.

[image]

My question is if we remove the $(1)$ of $ \Phi^{(1)}$ in the definition of $Y$ (i.e fifth line in
picture) does this affect the proof or not? (i.e if we use $Y= \phi (l(X_2),r(X_2))$ is True for $ K_0 \leq_1 K $ proof?) ?

Comment: The way this site works, it is not acceptable to re-ask a question that you have just asked, and which was closed. The new version is viewed as a "duplicate" of the old question.   Also, for any future questions, please do not include inapplicable tags.

Comment: I think that the reason that your original question is not drawing much interest is that it is not written in a very clear way. This question is also not very clearly written.

Comment: Dear @CarlMummert you are a professor. it's not a good way to refuse others, so learn me how to make it clear !?

Comment: Some things I changed: (i) you don't need to mention that you read Martin Davis' book a lot of times, that is not too important for people trying to help you, however explaining from which book your problem comes is always a good thing to do, (ii) I made it very clear what your question was, by starting on a new line and telling: "My question is ...", such that people don't need to look to long to find what you are actually asking, (iii) I made it shorter in general, then it is clear what the essence of the question is, (iv) I fixed some English errors I found but you can't do much about that

Comment: Also one last tip: best don't use the yellow quote box for other things as quoting things from a book. You used that yellow box, it looked nice and shiny ;), but people use it always here to cite things they found in a book. For instance, if you don't want to add the information from your book with a print screen as you did, people often use that yellow box. But in that box, they didn't found something from a book, but a part of your question, and that also made them a bit puzzling. As a general rule, people here want to see fast what your question is. ;)

Comment: The symbol $\Phi^{(1)}$ means the "universal" computable function with one argument; thus $\Phi^{(1)}(x,n)$  is "extensionally" equivalent to $\Phi_n(x)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  thanks so with above proof with $Y= \phi (l(X_2),r(X_2))$ is True that we say $ K_0 \leq_1 K $? am I right?

Comment: Right; the only care to be taken in omitting it is : do not "mix" the one-input universal function $\Phi^{(1)}(x,n)$ with the two-inputs universal function $\Phi^{(2)}(x,y,n)$.

Comment: Would you please submit as an answer @MauroALLEGRANZA ?